# Difference between below object declarations in java

Tags: java

I am kind of a Java newbie. Can you please explain the difference between below two pieces of code?

Piece 1:

```
Set<String> b = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
b = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
```

Piece 2:

```
Set<String> b =  webDriver.getWindowHandles()
```

My question is not on usage of set or selenium/webdriver. I basically want to understand the OOPs concept difference between the two declarations.

Comment: The first creates a new hash set then throws it away immediately. The second doesn't.

Comment: there is nothing about OOPs concept here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you are creating a new LinkedHashSet object, and then immediately replace it with another one. There is no reason to do that. It makes your code less readable and hurts performance.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, creates a new LinkedHashSet which is then thrown away when b is a assigned the result of the call to webDriver.getWidnowHandles, so it is useless.

The second one is correct.

Or if you need to declare b outside for some reason (for example, you the assign it inside an if, as shown below) you can write :

```
Set<String> b = null;
if (xxxxx) {
  b = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
} else {
  b = // something else
}
```

This is not about OOP, but about what the "new" operator does and how java manages references.

Answer (score 0):

First is useless as value of `b` in definition is directly overwritten with `webDriver.getWindowHandles()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set b = new LinkedHashSet(); b= webDriver.getWindowHandles();
```

In the above code,you are creating a LinkedHashset object first ,than second statement on the same is returning a new LinkedHashSet,So in this case first LinkedHashset object is not useful and unnecessary created.

```
Set b = webDriver.getWindowHandles()
```

While in this statement only one linked hashset is created.

So second one is more appropriate to use.

Answer (score 0):

`getWindowHandles()` It returns a set of window handles which can be used to iterate over all open windows of this WebDriver instance

```
Set<String> b = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
b= webDriver.getWindowHandles();  // This will invalidate the first assignment
```

and

```
Set<String> b =  webDriver.getWindowHandles() // This will prevent the unnecessary thing that you tried earlier
```